# function "pkcs12cert" not defined for externsecrets in helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, external-secrets-operator

I am trying to create tls secrets using `Externalsecret` and yaml file is created as below.

```
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1alpha1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: pgbouncer-serv
spec:
  refreshInterval: 5m
  secretStoreRef:
    kind: ClusterSecretStore
    name: env-secrets
  target:
    name: pgbouncer-serv
    creationPolicy: Owner
  template:
    type: kubernetes.io/tls
    engineVersion: v2
    data:
      tls.crt: "{{ .servsecret | pkcs12cert }}"
      tls.key: "{{ .servsecret | pkcs12key }}"
  data:
    - secretKey: servsecret
      remoteRef:
        key: SERV_CERT
```

we are trying create these external secrets in kubernetes cluster using helm chart, when i try to generate helm chart i am getting an error as `function "pkcs12cert" not defined`. can someone help me to rectify this error?

Answer (score 0):

Because the double curly brackets should not be interpreted by Helm but by the External Secrets Operator, you need to escape them. One solution for this would be to write the data section using `printf`:

```
data:
  tls.crt: {{ printf "'{{ .servsecret | pkcs12cert }}'" }}
  tls.key: {{ printf "'{{ .servsecret | pkcs12key }}'" }}
```